# Are the odd integers cofinal in the integers with the usual order?

Tags: terminology, order-theory

I think the definition I read of cofinal says there must always be an element of the subset which is greater than any given element. The odd numbers have this property, so they're cofinal, right?

Assuming that's correct, what do we call the property the positive integers have, in that there is always one above and never one of their complement above one of them?

Comment: Yes, the odd naturals are cofinal in the naturals.  You can just say that the negatives (the complement of the positives) are not cofinal in the integers.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan for clearing up point 1.  I'm actually looking for the term for a subset which is "final" in the sense the positive naturals are final in $\Bbb Z,>$

Comment: You need a defined order to talk about a subset being final.  The integers come with one.  I think cofinal is saying what you want.  It does not require that the other things run out, so the primes are cofinal in the integers.  Is that what you are looking for?  That was what I was trying to get at with the statement that the complement is not cofinal.

Comment: Thanks @RossMillikan so it sounds like "final" *is* the thing I want - I want to say the postive integers are final in the integers with $>$.